# Is there a program that can loop a youtube video?

Tags: 11.04, software-recommendation

I would like to loop [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pmfHHLfbjNQ) from YouTube, it's OK if it reloads every time although it would be nicer (and perhaps illegal ) to cache the video.

are there any suggestions on software that can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create an HTML document and then just open it when you want this. Open your favorite editor and paste these contents into it. Save it anywhere, and then double-click the saved file to open in a Web browser.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Music</title>
</head>
<body>
    <embed
        src="http://www.youtube.com/v/pmfHHLfbjNQ?autoplay=1&loop=1"
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        wmode="transparent"
        width="425"
        height="350">
    </embed>
</body>
</html>
```

Or just paste this in a browser and make a bookmark.

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/pmfHHLfbjNQ?autoplay=1&loop=1
```

Comment: could you clarify the command for looping a video? (there are no commercials as well! woho! :))

Comment: @Alvar Google has a great page on it: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html

Answer (score 2):

Do you need it to actually be in the browser while it's playing?

If not, one thing you can do is:

- Install youtube-dl
- Open a terminal (ctrl-alt-t), and use youtube-dl to download the video you want to loop. Something like:

> ```
> youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QH2-TGUlwu4
> ```

WARNING: paste the Youtube URL for the video *you* need, don't use this example.

- Play the downloaded .flv file with any video player capable of looping a video. I know vlc can do this (go to the playlist view for looping controls) but others might also work. Note that other video players may need you to install some additional codecs in order to be able to play .flv files.

Answer (score 1):

you can play any youtube video with vlc. `vlc <url of the video>`

if you go into vlc preferences, all preferences, and then playlist, tick the box `repeat current item`

then it will loop any video you play.

after you do that go to the terminal, and play your specific video:

```
vlc http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pmfHHLfbjNQ
```

it will keep looping. :)

Answer (score 1):

i recently find this site https://www.youtuberpt.com, it gives you a simple way how to loop youtube videos and create custom playlist with part of your favorite videos, maybe it will help others who was trying to find something like this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Enhancer for Youtube extension available for chrome and firefox.

[Chrome Link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enhancer-for-youtube/ponfpcnoihfmfllpaingbgckeeldkhle?hl=es) [Firefox Link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/enhancer-for-youtube/)

If you are on Android or iPhone then create playlist and then click on auto replay icon in the playlist.

Source: https://digitblogger.com/how-to-loop-youtube-videos/